# How can I use regular expression to grab an 'img' tag?

Tags: regex, image, html-parsing

I want to grab an `img` tag from text returned from JSON data like that. I want to grab this from a string:

```
<img class="img" src="https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/1239478_598075296936250_1910331324_s.jpg" alt="" />
```

What is the regular expression I must use to match it?

I used the following, but it is not working.

```
"<img[^>]+src\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/775544

Comment: Please don't parse HTML with regex. HTML is not a regular language.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: If i am want to get all the attributes (title, src, alt), what are the modifications needed with the regex pattern <img\s+[^>]*src="([^"]*)"[^>]*>. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27):

You could simply use this expression to match an img tag as in the example :

```
<img([\w\W]+?)/>
```

Comment: OP didn't say what he wanted to capture but this captures the class, src, and alt tag.

Comment: @hwnd yes, I know. But as you said he haven't specified what he wants to capture .

Comment: Html can't really be parsed effectively with regex, adding some  granularity in the expression betters the odds though.

Comment: regexr.com complains that closing slash needs to be closed AND closing slash itself is optional, depending on is it HTML or XHTML. Better way would be: `<img([\w\W]+?)[\/]?>`, what do you think?

Answer (score 20):

Your regex doesn't match the string, because it's missing the closing `/`.

Edit - No, the `/` is not necessary, so your regex should have worked. But you can relax it a bit like below.

Slightly modified:

```
 <img\s[^>]*?src\s*=\s*['\"]([^'\"]*?)['\"][^>]*?>
```

Answer (score 10):

Please note you shouldn't use regular expressions to parse HTML for the various reasons

```
<img\s+[^>]*src="([^"]*)"[^>]*>
```

Or use `Jsoup`...

```
String html = "<img class=\"img\" src=\"https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/
               hphotos-ak-frc3/1239478_598075296936250_1910331324_s.jpg\" alt=\"\" />";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element img = doc.select("img").first();
String src = img.attr("src");

System.out.println(src);
```

Comment: are jsoup better than it ??

Comment: Yea just use `String imgall = img.outerHtml(); System.out.println(imgall);`

Comment: Jsoup's performance of the parse method leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: If i am want to get all the attributes (title, src, alt), what are the modifications needed with the above regex pattern. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same situation and I tried this and it worked for me.

`(<img)[^/>]*(/>|>)`

Here is the explanation:

[image: Image for the explanation of above regex]

This explanation is from the website https://extendsclass.com/regex-tester.html

Comment: I think your slashes are backward. Should be the following so that characters are properly escaped.

(<img)[^\>]*(\>|>)

Comment: @AlexMacArthur these slashes are not for escaping any character but it's to check the slash itself in string. eg. <img src="xyz" />